# VirtualBox VBoxManage --videocapopts

Tags: virtualbox

The [VirtualBox VBoxManage documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) says:

> `--videocapopts <key=value> [,<key=value> ...]`: This format can be used to specify additional video capturing options. These options only are for advanced users and must be specified in a comma-separated key=value format, e.g. `foo=bar,a=b`.

That's all well and good, but I cannot find *what* those specific advanced options might be.  Is there a list somewhere?

I tried Googling for the relevant source code, but failed to find what I was looking for.